# Microsoft.VersionNumber.targets was not found

Tags: version-numbering

When I want to open solition with 5 project I get an error as below for one project

"\AssemblyInfoTask\Microsoft.VersionNumber.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a line in the project that is referencing the MSBuild task for incrementing version numbers.  You must not have MSBuildExtensions installed.  You can either install MSBuild (properly) or remove it (see below).

Look for this line and remove it:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\AssemblyInfoTask\Microsoft.VersionNumber.targets">
```

**Be aware that you may be removing important functionality so you may not want to check it back in.**